Postgres split time ranges into 1 minute slots, without rounding boundaries
I have a postgres table with timestamp columns:



start_datetime
end_datetime
duration
id




2021-10-17 03:13:00
2021-10-17 03:15:02
302
6214550


2021-10-17 03:15:02
2021-10-17 03:17:03
4,021
6214551



which i need to split out in to buckets constrained to either the end of the minute or the end_datetime as:



start_datetime
end_datetime
id




2021-10-17 03:13:00
2021-10-17 03:14:00
6214550


2021-10-17 03:14:00
2021-10-17 03:15:00
6214550


2021-10-17 03:15:00
2021-10-17 03:15:02
6214550


2021-10-17 03:15:02
2021-10-17 03:16:00
6214551


2021-10-17 03:16:00
2021-10-17 03:17:00
6214551


2021-10-17 03:17:00
2021-10-17 03:17:03
6214551




Cross join each row to a generate_series() to spawn the 1-minute slots, use greatest() and least() to keep the non-aligned start and end timestamps.
demo at db<>fiddle
select greatest(slot,start_datetime)   as start_datetime
     , least(slot+'1min',end_datetime) as end_datetime
     , id
from test
cross join lateral generate_series( date_trunc('minute',start_datetime)
                                   ,end_datetime
                                   ,'1min') as slot;




start_datetime
end_datetime
id




2021-10-17 03:13:00
2021-10-17 03:14:00
6214550


2021-10-17 03:14:00
2021-10-17 03:15:00
6214550


2021-10-17 03:15:00
2021-10-17 03:15:02
6214550


2021-10-17 03:15:02
2021-10-17 03:16:00
6214551


2021-10-17 03:16:00
2021-10-17 03:17:00
6214551


2021-10-17 03:17:00
2021-10-17 03:17:03
6214551




This method worked the best
